# Tests do not run when dependency on mockito-core present

Tags: java, maven, mockito, powermockito

I've added `mockito-core` to my dependencies but I seem to be unable to run tests (errors when running) unless I also add `powermock-api-mockito` to the dependencies. I start getting errors immediately after I put in the `mockito-core` dependency - no other changes are necessary (e.g. I don't need to add code that uses Mockito to start seeing errors).

Dependency I want to add:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Dependency I seem to need to include along:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Without the above second dependency, I get the following errors. Again, this is purely dependency changes, no code changes:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
```

And this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/internal/matchers/StacktracePrintingMatcher

    at org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.isThrowable(JUnitMatchers.java:103)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedExceptionMatcherBuilder.build(ExpectedExceptionMatcherBuilder.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.handleException(ExpectedException.java:252)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.access$000(ExpectedException.java:106)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:241)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be solved by using mockito-all instead of mockito-core. It would have all the dependency required by mockito. hamcrest and junit are part of it.

Comment: As you can read here https://site.mockito.org/ 'Recommended way of getting Mockito is declaring a dependency on “mockito-core” library using your favorite build system.'

Answer (score 1):

Mockito-core **1.10.19** has no dependencies to the powermock-api-mockito. The only dependencies it has are following runtime dependencies:

- org.hamcrest » hamcrest-core 1.1
- org.objenesis » objenesis    2.1

Maybe these are conflicting with another library you have in your dependencies tree. Try to analyze your dependency tree using:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19